# How to perform minimal KDE installation on 18.04.1?

Tags: 18.04, kde

I like the KDE desktop environment for Ubuntu, but I need none of the fluff it installs - such as VLC. How can  I perform a minimal KDE installation on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS?

Comment: `sudo apt install kde-plasma-desktop`